# GridView DataKeyName for a DropDownList Select Statement

Tags: c#, asp.net

When the user selects a row to edit I have a dropdownlist as one of the controls.  In order for me to populate that ddl I need one of the datakeyname values (there are three).  I was guessing that I could retrieve this value when the OnEditing event fired and pass it to the select statement for the ddl.  Just not sure how to do this.  I am using a stored procedure to query the Database.

This is my sqldatasource for the ddl -

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceDebtor" runat="server" 
                            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AuditDevConnectionString2 %>" 
                            SelectCommand="sp_fc_vm_getDebtorList" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" DefaultValue="0" Name="ClientKey" 
                                    PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
      </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The "ClientKey" is the datakeyname value I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple approach to do this, please check http://weblogs.asp.net/aghausman/archive/2009/01/08/get-primary-key-on-row-command-gridview.aspx

Let me know if you want anything specific other than this.

Comment: how do I go about setting the value to pass to the select query?

Comment: If you not set the CommandArgument property of your Edit button you can do the foloowing to get the value of dropdownlist in gridview.            int rownum = Convert.Int32(e.CommandArgument);                            GridViewRow oRow = gdvID.Rows[rownum];                                  int ddlSelectedValue = ((DropDownList)oRow.findControl("YourDropDownID")).SelectedValue;       Hope that's what you are looking for. Let me know if I still doesnt answered ur question.

Answer (score 0):

I did a post on this a while back here:  http://peterkellner.net/2006/10/14/showallingridviewfromddl/